# more servers or more u's per server?

Tags: mysql, virtualization

I'm considering an upgrade in my servers.  I can not decide if I want more servers, or fewer servers with a high unit thickness and possible virtualization.  My servers have high mySQL query demand and low storage requirements.  All opinions are welcome.

-Storm

Comment: So what I'm understanding is that the value of more U's is the ability to add more adapters, storage, and it has the potential for a greater overall data transfer rate. The down side is that you need to pay for virtualization and the cost of power consumption increases due to the CPU's being spread over more boxes. As scott points out, the best is probably a hybrid option , but ill still wait to see if anyone else weighs in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real reason to get "taller" servers is if you need more storage or many PCI[e|x] IO cards. Other than that, CPU, RAM, etc can be, in most cases, identical between 1U servers and 2,4,6U servers.

Comment: In addition, "taller" servers will sometimes be equipped with additional power supply sockets or proc sockets.

Answer (score 4):

This is an absurdly scoped question.  We would need to know *much* more about your workload and datacenter to provide advice more useful than flipping a coin.

So thats my advice.  Flip a coin.

Comment: In no way is this a helpful answer. Should have been a comment at most.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation I'd advise you to look at the number and type of any PCIe/X adapters needed.

If you NEED specific adapters then that may preclude you from using blades. That said most SQL servers simply need a few NICs, a couple of CPUs, a decent amount of memory and maybe a FC SAN HBA to central storage - if that's enough then I'd suggest blades as they can significantly reduce space and power requirement while still hitting compute targets. They're also usually highly resilient/redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The classic question! Power vs Redundancy!

I tend to come down on the side of redundancy; with modern hardware clustering, you can take any number decent machines and cluster them into one very nice machine. Add a SAN, connect them all to it, and you've got the best of both worlds. Or just share the drives in your local machines, depending on your storage needs.

Answer (score 0):

Fewer servers with more storage would mean less power use and the possibility of using virtualization to create as many systems as you'd need, especially if you have gigabit in place for networking.

This depends on your I/O demand, as you could create issues with disk access if you don't think that out ahead of time. Personally I'd want to find out if the load can be adequately placed on a couple VMWare servers, depending on money and configuration needs. Get a couple and license the features for live migration for some redundancy and then you have space for whatever servers you want to set up down the road while saving power and not wasting CPU cycles on idle systems.

Comment: i was thinking of using something virtualBox, so i may start fiddling with that pretty soon.

Comment: VirtualBox is mainly for desktop virtualization, like a workstation within a workstation. VMWare (like ESXi, free) creates servers that are for servers, accessed over the network and administrated via a Windows console application called VSphere. If you're looking at server virtualization you'll want to skip to VMWare or XenSource or Hyper-V, as they're for servers, while Virtualbox is your guy when you need to run Microsoft Office and you're running Linux on your system.

Comment: I'll add that we're using VMWare ESXi on a system with 7 servers in it, which I sometimes oversee running VSphere in Windows in Virtualbox on Linux...talk about virtual abstraction! :-)

Comment: thanks for saving me 10 hours of pain and suffering. ill check that out more too.

Answer (score 0):

How about option C which is server consolidation with the smallest physical footprint possible.  Rack space and power is often expensive, so the more you can consolidate while still having high levels of redundancy and performance, the better.

Sometimes blade servers work great too, even for high density situation, especially if they are redundant.  Blade servers can often support 4 NICs, plenty of RAM and plenty of CPUs.  Centralizing storage on a SAN helps a lot too although you can use local storage depending on how large of an environment you're talking about.

What I suggest is to map out your most common scenarios and consider rack space, licensing, power costs, support, hardware costs and support costs.  Different situations and environments will have different 'best' options.

Comment: good idea.  off to excel

Answer (score 0):

Your "Tall" servers are often called "Big Iron", and there's an excellent writeup about the hidden costs on Jeff Atwood's blog, [juuust over here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001279.html).

Whilst not covering your usage of the servers, the fundamentals of the article are the same - a few massive servers, or dozens of smaller ones. It should help you narrow down your choices based on a few metrics you may not have covered.